# An Inequality Regarding Brownian Motions Starting at Different Places

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Denote $P^m$ as the probability distribution of a d-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $m \in D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$. Let $x_0 \in \partial D$. Let $\tau_D$ be the random hitting time and suppose we know $\tau_D < h$. Let $\delta >0$

Why is it true that:
$$P^x\bigg(\sup_{t \in [0,h]}|B_t-x_0|\geq \delta \bigg) \leq P^0 \bigg(\sup_{t \in [0,h]}|B_t+x-x_0|\geq \delta \bigg)$$

Comment: The hitting time seems to be unused. It is the hitting time for what exactly? So the probabilities are conditional on the hitting time less than h? Can you check and clarify?

Comment: it's part of a bigger argument, i narrowed a giant inequality down to the piece I didn't understand. It could be its not used to understand this part, I just added it in case it was.

Comment: What is $\tau_D$?  The exit time $\inf\{t: B_t\notin D\}$ perhaps?

Comment: @JohnDawkins yes it is indeed. I should have added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These probabilities are actually equal. By [translation invariance](https://books.google.ca/books?id=evbGTPhuvSoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=durrett%20probability%20translation%20invariance&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW1pTozoncAhVYHDQIHcZJC0sQ6AEITzAH#v=onepage&q=Translation%20invariance&f=false), i.e. $\{B_t-B_0,t\ge 0\}$ is independent of $B_0$ and has the same law as a BM starting at zero, we have

\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}^x\left(\sup_{t \in [0,h]}|B_t-x_0|\geq \delta \right) &=\mathsf{P}^0 \left(\sup_{t \in [0,h]}|B_t+x-x_0|\geq \delta \right) \\
&= \mathsf{P}^{x-x_0} \left(\sup_{t \in [0,h]}|B_t|\geq \delta \right).
\end{align}

Comment: I thought they were equal too but figured i was missing something since OP had unused info.

Comment: When I read the proof for translation invariance I see its true. When I draw the pictures associated with my questions, I see that its consistent with your claim. I'm having trouble writing it out formally. Could you provide more detail on, perhaps, the first equality?

Comment: @jdods ya, the book I'm using just uses "one direction of the equality" without mentioning anything else

Comment: Given the definition of $\tau_D$, this argument doesn't stand, because $\tau_D$ is *not* translation invariant.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Sure. But $h$ is constant and the question is about the supremum of a translated BM over a fixed interval. If not, then the question should be properly restated.

Comment: @yoshi What book are you talking about?

Comment: I'm using Brownian Motion by Schilling and Partzsch. In particular, I'm looking at a proof that verifies that BM solves the Dirichlet Problem. This part of the proof checks continuity to the boundary. In particular, he breaks up the analysis into three pieces that are individually analyzed. I refer here to the second integral he analyzes. The relevant portion is here: https://pasteboard.co/HtoMiln.png

Comment: You can see, $I_2$ goes from being estimated at $P^x$ to being estimated at $P^0$ at the end. $\tau$ here is an exit time from the domain (on which we wish to solve the dirichlet problem).

Comment: @yoshi OK. Then the stopping time is irrelevant here. They use equality between two probabilities and the fact that
$$
|f(B_{\tau})-f(x_0)|\le 2\|f\|_{\infty}.
$$

Comment: @yoshi Regarding your first question. In all 3 cases you have stochastic processes starting at $x-x_0$ and having the same law, which implies that the distributions of the suprema are the same.